How to choose a SEO friendly URL structure for user generated content?
I am currently designing the URL structure for a web application serving user generated content.
For SEO purposes, I want the user generated name in the URL, e.g. example.com/collection/user-generated-name.
However, this creates conflicts, when two users choose the same name.
As a first solution, I appended a number, e.g. example.com/collection/user-generated-name-[1-N].
I do not want to imply hierarchy, though.
As a second solution, I replaced the number with a random string, e.g. example.com/collection/user-generated-name-[random].
Now I ponder which SEO implications this might have and whether there is a better option. Possible adjustments I can think of are:

Format of the random part (length, use letters or numbers only, use letters and numbers mixed, ...)
Position of the random part

append with a dash: user-generated-name-[random]
append with a slash: user-generated-name/[random]
prepend with a dash: [random]-user-generated-name
prepend with a slash: [random]/user-generated-name (This option has the added benefit of providing a natural way to create short URLs by dropping the user generated name)



Can you explain the implications on SEO and whether there is any preferable solution?
Btw: I read this remotely related question and the very informative accepted answer, but am unsure how this applies to my question.

I don't like random stuff in URLs. Search engines will try to make some sense of it, and although it's quite unique, so it must be important, it doesn't mean anything in the end. Then again, you see this everywhere. My suggestion would be to try and use relevant information in the URL.

The append/prepend question is answered by What is the best placement for the ID in a URL for SEO?

The slashes vs dashes question is answered by Use forward slashes (/) or dashes (-) for URL design in 2019? (for categories in e-commerce)

[random]-user-generated-name could also function as a short URL by dropping the first dash and everything after it.  I don't see a big difference between the slash and the dash in this case.

I can't think of any specific SEO problems with any of those approaches (assuming the random number does not change once generated).  It's a good idea to keep the URL as human readable as possible, but that's more for usability.
It's worth noting that the numbers you see in a URL are rarely just random.
If you prepend, that's likely to be some form of unique ID and the page uses that information to identify the user when generating the page, instead of their potentially not-unique username. All users would have a string here, not just those with a conflicting username.
If you append to a username, you may want to allow the user to change their username if that annoys them.
However, if your users aren't expected to use real names, then I'd consider forcing them to pick a unique username if there is a conflict.  Depending on the site's purpose, the ability to create two identical usernames could create confusion with users, and potentially be used by scammers.
